# JFreeChart some ChartMouseEvent are skipped

Tags: java, jfreechart

Recently I'm trying to implement a simple `ChartMouseListener` in **JFreeChart** and I recognized the problem that not each event causes listener reaction. It's just a simple code:

```
chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void chartMouseMoved(final ChartMouseEvent event) {
            }

            @Override
            public void chartMouseClicked(final ChartMouseEvent event) {
                final ChartEntity entity = event.getEntity();
                System.out.println(event.getTrigger().getWhen());
        });
```

Not each 'click' event causes system out. Is it a bug or I'm doing sth wrong?

Comment: I think that the problem occurs when you click to fast. So it seems that the problem is that events are not queued?! But it is hard to say if it has anything to do with clicking frequency, sometimes I give him a little bit of time and also no reaction, bad!

Comment: It seems that awt mouse clicked is not always executed. I tried kind of workaround with   chartPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

   
   
   @Override
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    super.mouseReleased(e);
    chartPanel.getMouseListeners()[1].mouseClicked(e);
   }... and released event is always catched properly

Comment: It seems odd not to get the mouse clicks, do you know if the behaviour consistent across platforms?

Comment: I don't know. My configuration is JFree ver. 16. JDK7_51, Windows 7. I stabilized the behaviour with such ugly workaround   chartPanel.addMouseListener(new JFreeChartMouseAdapter() {

   
   public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getButton() == 1) {
     if (!isActionExecuted()) {
      chartPanel.getMouseListeners()[1].mouseClicked(e);
     }
     setActionExecuted(false);
    }
   }

   
   public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getButton() == 1) {
     setActionExecuted(true);
    }
   }

  });

Comment: Concerned graph is   JFreeChart chart = org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory.createXYBarChart("",
    "", false, "", null, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true,
    false);